# ListView containing Bitmaps with Zoom Animation in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a simple requirement as mentioned below:

A ListView or any control displays list of bitmaps/images. When user mouse hovers on any bitmap that bitmap zoomed to show that is currently selected.

Since I have to provide drag drop operations and click operation that why I taken the list view.

Pleas help!!

It will be great if any body provide the xaml to this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short - use render transform (or layout transform) scaling to zoom in on the pictures with mouse hover.

Sorry for the long listing - animation are very long in wrting :) Hope this helps.

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
x:Name="Window"
Title="MainWindow"
Width="640" Height="480">
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1.5"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="1.5"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.ZIndex)">
                                <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="0"/>
                                <SplineInt32KeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.3000000" Value="0"/>
                            </Int32AnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                        <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseLeave1">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.5"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)">
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="1.5"/>
                                <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000" Value="1"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Grid Background="{x:Null}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseLeave">
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseLeave1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseLeave1}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard x:Name="OnMouseEnter1_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
                        </EventTrigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <ListView ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle1}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <Image Width="64" Height="64" Source="167.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Width="64" Height="64" Source="167.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Width="64" Height="64" Source="167.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Width="64" Height="64" Source="167.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Image Width="64" Height="64" Source="167.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks Jefim for xaml that really helps me.. 

Few queries I want to ask:
1.Since I am using doc manager , I want if user doc my control to the bottom the all the images are alligned horizantally.

2. How can set the background of the listview to some other color like black. I am setting the Background property to Black in the listview but it doesn't take affect.

Again many thanks for the solution!!

Comment: Editing the background should work (works for me).
As for the doc manager question - you can edit the ListView control template and use a FlowPanel to host items. This will ensure that it wraps the items according to the space available to the control. Another possibility - use StackPanel as items host and set its orientation when the user chooses the doc mode.

Comment: The zooming works great, however I can not get the Panel.ZIndex to work. I see in your storyboard that it goes from 0 to 0 and there is also a trigger that sets it to 100. The zoomed item does not go before the other items though.